# Remove the rendered application template

Tags: ember.js, routes

I have quite many templates that I render into the application template. The application template, however, has only the `{{outlet}}` and nothing else.

The `home` template, must render directly into the application template. But all other templates must be rendered along with the `navbar` and `sidebar`.

Currently, I am using `partial` to render the common data in all the other templates (except 'home')

How can I solve this scenario? All I need is that home should render directly in the body, while all the other templates must render along with the navbar and sidebar.

I might be missing something very obvious here. What should I do to render home in one template and the rest in another?

**UPDATE 1**

Application Template

```
  {{#unless renderNav}}
    {{outlet home}}
  {{else}}
    {{partial 'navbar'}}
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
          {{outlet}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
          <div class="list-group">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
          </div>
        </div><!--/span-->
      </div><!--/row-->
    </div><!--/.container-->
  {{/unless}}
```

**UPDATE 2**

The above code causes rendering problems. Navigating to the home template causes no issue. But in all other templates, the first page rendered stays on the top while the next pages are rendered below it.

For example, if after 'home', I transition to 'first', 'first' renders two elements `A and B`.
If I next transition to 'second', which renders C, what I get is `A and B and C`, instead of `C`.

**UPDATE 3**

Solved the error in the previous UPDATE by observing the `currentPath` property in the application controller. But now in the 'home' route, the 'home' template is not displayed. Instead the navbar is rendered with an empty outlet.

I renamed my outlets and forced HomeRoute to render into `outlet 'home'`. But still there is no change. All other templates are rendered seamlessly, but 'home' is not rendered at all.

I confirmed that the boolean was `false` in the HomeRoute, but still the navbar template is being rendered.

Comment: I believe your error has to do with placing more than one {{outlet}}
on the same template (even if these two are conditionally visible or not). I suggest you keep your template as it is and try what @ianpetzer suggested , but only for the home template. That is replace your first outlet by an {{outlet home}} you create.

Comment: Did you tried the above? (named outlet for home)

Comment: I didn't notice these comments before. Updated my question..

Answer (score 2):

You can create a template where `navbar` and `sidebar` can be rendered in and all templates except `home` are nested routes of this new template.
This of course can give you trouble with url, so another way to go is to use a boolean computed property in the `application` controller based on `currentPath` that renders or not your partials

e.g.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    showPartials: (function() {
      this.get('currentPath') != 'home' 
    }).property('currentPath')
});
```

Then in your application template do something like

```
{{#if showPartials}}
  {{partial "navbar"}}
  {{partial "sidebar"}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: An issue here is that in the other templates, the view that is rendered first remains fixed, the new route templates are rendered below one by one. Why is this so?

Comment: Im not sure I get you. Can you post the part of your template?

Comment: The function must observe the currentPath property. Otherwise it will keep rendering into the template generated the first time.